# Facebook registration cuts off (XFBML)

Tags: facebook, registration, xfbml

we offer our users the ability to use facebook to sign up on our site and until recently this was working fine.

Since 2 days ago (October 30th) we noticed our registrations using facebook significantly dropped (from around 50-100/day down to 1!) and when taking a look at the process we found that the registration was being cut off and only a small part was showing.

This is how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilmis.jpg

If I look at the source of the facebook iframe I can see the html tag has overflow set to hidden and if I disable this using Firebug everything looks as it should. But since this is on facebooks end there's nothing I can do about it to prevent it happening to our customers.

Has anyone else run in to this problem and found a solution?

The bug has been reported to facebook here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/471852109598483/

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Looks like the iframe included (FB code) have a overflow:hidden attached to it preventing the whole frame to render. I have contacted FB developers, still no answer.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same issue.  After screwing around with it for a bit, I discovered that if I modified the "origin" url in the iframe's src attribute, the iframe rendered correctly.  But that doesn't exactly help, as I don't know what the origin url is used for and so it might be necessary, and if using XFBML, the iframe's src property is generated automatically.